# Is there a limit to how rapidly python evdev can write/inject to an input device?

Tags: python, linux, input, gamepad, evdev

I have a python program that uses evdev to simulate gamepad button presses. The device used is [*"cloned"* from](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#create-uinput-device-with-capabilities-of-another-device) an xbox usb gamepad, by using `ui = evdev.UInput.from_device(...)`

But for some reason it seems that the presses is sometimes inconsistent.

Below is the function i use to simulate an A button tap:

```
def press_A_button():
    ui.write(evdev.ecodes.EV_KEY, evdev.ecodes.BTN_A, 1)
    ui.write(evdev.ecodes.EV_SYN, 0, 0)
    sleep(0.01)
    ui.write(evdev.ecodes.EV_KEY, evdev.ecodes.BTN_A, 0)
    ui.write(evdev.ecodes.EV_SYN, 0, 0)
    sleep(0.01)
```

If i remove the `sleep`'s altogether, it seems no presses will register at all. Albeit `0.01` seems to be too rapid as well, causing it to appear to not register/skip a tap every now and then. *(i simply use jstest-gtk to watch how it behaves)*

Here's how i test the function:

```
while True:
    try:
        press_A_button()
        # putting a sleep here, e.g a sleep(2), seemingly still doesn't
        # keep it from sometimes missing the tap
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ui.close()
        break
```

**So is there some way to figure out the optimal timing that should be used for it to work consistently?**

Or could the problem perhaps not be with my code, but the polling rate of the other software *(in this case jstest-gtk)* ?

A *possibly* related issue:

[Simulating controller dpad button being held down with Python evdev](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62128479/6280870)

Comment: I recommend you to study the kernel input module sources here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/input .

Comment: I _think_ jstest-gtk does not rely on polling; if I understand correctly it's performing async I/O [here](https://gitlab.com/jstest-gtk/jstest-gtk/-/blob/master/src/joystick.cpp#L81).

Comment: @Roadowl unfortunately my C knowledge is a bit too weak to properly figure out what i should be looking for